# The shop has almost like a club-house atmosphere to it

Tags: grammar, parts-of-speech

I read this sentence on [a webpage](https://www.theindustry.fashion/tom-holmes-managing-director-and-co-founder-wax-london/).

> The shop has almost **like** a club-house atmosphere to it, which is what
> we wanted, with a sofa in the middle of the store and bench seating
> outside.

I know 'like' is a preposition in the sentences such as
'*This podium spot feels almost like a victory.*' and '*It's almost like a habit*.'.

I wonder what part of speech the word in bold 'like' is in the above context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the context of the example, the [part-of-speech](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/like) of *like* is an adjective-combining-form. These are relatively rare.

The structure of the sentence should combine *like* and *club-house* as

> *The shop has a **clubhouselike** atmosphere to it....[etc.]*

Comment: Would it not be better to hyphenate the adjective? Don’t you think “almost” is also part of it?

Comment: I'm uncertain about the rules for hyphenating adjectival combining forms. My opinion is that it ought to be written as I have it. "Almost" is not part of it, although there is an adjectival combining form which we might use in place of "almost", and thus write "quasi-clubhouselike"—but as one can see, that would be redundant, as "almost/quasi" and "like" have very similar meanings. (I shall edit my original proposal to remove "almost".)